# Lenovo Recovery Media creation says C drive does not have enough space

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad W541. I want to create the factory recovery discs.

I have put in a blank CD to start with the process (it says that it doesn't support DVD-RAM for Disc 1).

My C: hard drive has 100 GBs free space (it has 454 GB total capacity). Drive Q: is a 21.8 GB partition with 13 GBs of data.

I select both "Boot Media" and "Data Media" because I want a full set of recovery discs (CD + DVDs). A popup shows quickly saying that the files are being extracted, and then the following error dialog pops up:

[image: Not enough disk space in C error dialog]

How is this possible? I have 100 GB of free space! How much more can it need?

The `recovburncd.log` file has the following:

```
05/15/18 21:50:33: recovburncd starts
05/15/18 21:50:33: execute cmd /c mkdir c:\swshare\boot
05/15/18 21:50:34: execute1 cmd returncode = 0 ShExecInfo.hInstApp=42 GetLastError=0
05/15/18 21:50:34: execute cmd /c mkdir c:\swshare\app
05/15/18 21:50:34: execute1 cmd returncode = 0 ShExecInfo.hInstApp=42 GetLastError=0
05/15/18 21:50:34: Entering DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:34: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:34: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:34: Checking driver C:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:34: DeviceIoControl failed
05/15/18 21:50:34: the drive:Q: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:34: Checking driver Q:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:34: Entering DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:34: RunProgram pszCmdLine = C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~2\Lenovo\FACTOR~1\searchQ.cmd
05/15/18 21:50:35: Find 1 Lenovo partitions
05/15/18 21:50:35: Leaving DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:35: Already get recovery file without mount_q, this should be LI machines, get Q drive is Q
05/15/18 21:50:35: get the Q letter=Q:
05/15/18 21:50:35: Leaving DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:35: Entering DriverMgr::close_sp_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:35: Leaving DriverMgr::close_sp_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:35: Entering CMainDlg::OnInitDialog ...
05/15/18 21:50:35: Leaving CMainDlg::OnInitDialog ...
05/15/18 21:50:39: boot is 1, app is 1
05/15/18 21:50:39: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:39: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:39: before mount S, get winre file is C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winRE.wim
05/15/18 21:50:39: Before mount S, set s driver is C:
05/15/18 21:50:39: sp letter=C:
05/15/18 21:50:39: Entering DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:39: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:39: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:39: Checking driver C:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:39: DeviceIoControl failed
05/15/18 21:50:39: the drive:Q: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:39: Checking driver Q:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:39: Entering DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:39: RunProgram pszCmdLine = C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~2\Lenovo\FACTOR~1\searchQ.cmd
05/15/18 21:50:40: Find 1 Lenovo partitions
05/15/18 21:50:40: Leaving DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: Already get recovery file without mount_q, this should be LI machines, get Q drive is Q
05/15/18 21:50:40: get the Q letter=Q:
05/15/18 21:50:40: Leaving DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: Entering ProgressDlg::OnInitDialog ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: Leaving ProgressDlg::OnInitDialog ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:40: Entering Entering DriverMgr::get_disk_style ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: Disk Number passed in: 0
05/15/18 21:50:40: Leaving Entering DriverMgr::get_disk_style ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: In check_s_resource get drive is C:
05/15/18 21:50:40: Entering DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:40: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:40: Checking driver C:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:40: DeviceIoControl failed
05/15/18 21:50:40: the drive:Q: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:40: Checking driver Q:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:40: Entering DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:40: RunProgram pszCmdLine = C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~2\Lenovo\FACTOR~1\searchQ.cmd
05/15/18 21:50:42: Find 1 Lenovo partitions
05/15/18 21:50:42: Leaving DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: Already get recovery file without mount_q, this should be LI machines, get Q drive is Q
05/15/18 21:50:42: get the Q letter=Q:
05/15/18 21:50:42: Leaving DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: Entering ProgressDlg::OnDestroy ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: Leaving ProgressDlg::OnDestroy ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: Entering DriverMgr::get_disk_used_space ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: Now to calculate size path is:C:
05/15/18 21:50:42: Leaving DriverMgr::get_disk_used_space ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: Entering DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:42: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:42: Checking driver C:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:42: DeviceIoControl failed
05/15/18 21:50:42: the drive:Q: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:42: Checking driver Q:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:42: Entering DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:42: RunProgram pszCmdLine = C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~2\Lenovo\FACTOR~1\searchQ.cmd
05/15/18 21:50:44: Find 1 Lenovo partitions
05/15/18 21:50:44: Leaving DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:44: Already get recovery file without mount_q, this should be LI machines, get Q drive is Q
05/15/18 21:50:44: get the Q letter=Q:
05/15/18 21:50:44: Leaving DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:44: Entering DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:44: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:44: the drive:C: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:44: Checking driver C:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:44: DeviceIoControl failed
05/15/18 21:50:44: the drive:Q: in disk is:0
05/15/18 21:50:44: Checking driver Q:, and type is 3, disk index is 0, and isremoveable is 0
05/15/18 21:50:44: Entering DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:44: RunProgram pszCmdLine = C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\PROGRA~2\Lenovo\FACTOR~1\searchQ.cmd
05/15/18 21:50:45: Find 1 Lenovo partitions
05/15/18 21:50:45: Leaving DriverMgr::mount_q ...
05/15/18 21:50:45: Already get recovery file without mount_q, this should be LI machines, get Q drive is Q
05/15/18 21:50:45: get the Q letter=Q:
05/15/18 21:50:45: Leaving DriverMgr::get_q_driver ...
05/15/18 21:50:45: Entering DriverMgr::get_disk_used_space ...
05/15/18 21:50:45: Now to calculate size path is:Q:
05/15/18 21:50:45: Leaving DriverMgr::get_disk_used_space ...
05/15/18 21:50:45: Entering DriverMgr::get_disk_free_space ...
05/15/18 21:50:45: Now to calculate size path is:c:
05/15/18 21:50:45: Leaving DriverMgr::get_disk_free_space ...
```

Comment: 100gb may not be enough, I would try to clear some disc space and try again.

Comment: How can it not be enough? How big would a USB drive need to be to store the recovery partition? Even an entire copy of the recovery partition would be less than 100 GB, so it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Its the temp files it needs to create could be larger that 100gb.